# UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, python-unicode

I can't figure out why 2 of my strings can't be compared and match.

```
warn_msg = ('Přihlášení bylo neúspěšné.') # Translated as: Login Failed.

soup = BeautifulSoup(auth, 'lxml')
find_login = soup.find("div", class_="box").text # Will Give: 'Přihlášení bylo neúspěšné.'' # Translated as: 'Login Failed.'

"""
find_login returns: 'Přihlášení bylo neúspěšné.
"""

if find_login == warn_msg:
    print('Nothing')
```

When I compare bs4 string with my var `warn_msg` they are equal but python thinks otherwise.  If I only use `requests` without `bs4` and slice the parsed string from the html and compare them it = True. I am confused why it seems to not work with bs4. I looked at the manual for encoding here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ but I didn't get it working.

Error I get:

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

Here is just my working example using only `requests`

```
for i in passwords:
    auth = requests.post(login_url, headers=headers, data=payload).content[7838:7872]
    if auth == warn_msg:
        print('It works, strings match')
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\petr>E:\Scripting\python\test.py
It works, strings match
```

Comment: Can you post result of ```import difflib
print(list(difflib.ndiff(find_login,warn_msg)))``` here?

Comment: @LazyCoder C:\Python27\lib\difflib.py:433: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  a[besti-1] == b[bestj-1]:
C:\Python27\lib\difflib.py:437: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  a[besti+bestsize] == b[bestj+bestsize]:
C:\Python27\lib\difflib.py:976: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if ai == bj:
[u'- \n', u'  P', u'- \u0159', '+ \x

Comment: Can you check and print```type(find_login) , type(warn_msg)``` here?

Comment: @LazyCoder I can see why it complains now: find_login:  <type 'unicode'>
warn_msg:  <type 'str'>

Comment: There you have your answer. Convert the str type to unicode and your code is golden

Comment: @LazyCoder thank you, that solved my issue

Comment: Or use Python 3 and sidestep the whole problem. This is one of the reasons Python 3 exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments discussion:

Please find the type of both strings in this kind of scenario. In this specific case, one is type Unicode and other is type string. Converting the string type to Unicode and then comparing two strings can help resolve the issue faster.

Happy Coding :) @uzdisral

Comment: If it is fixed, can you upvote and accept this answer, so that we can close this question?